# Can Crystal's HTTP:Server drop privileges?

Tags: crystal-lang

Some servers start on a privileged port (sub-1024 port, root privileges needed), start listening on the port, then drop privileges (change to a non-root user).  Can Crystal's `HTTP::Server` do anything similar?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the LibC bindings to drop privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558121/841803):

```
# Code below is for: Crystal 1.0.0

# Changing the process' uid: 
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/47558121/841803
lib LibC
  fun setuid(uid_t : Int)
  fun getuid : Int
end


# Documentation of System::User:
# https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/System/User.html
#
require "system/user"
NEW_UID = System::User.find_by(name: "my-sys-usr").id.to_i

require "http/server"

server = HTTP::Server.new do |context|
  context.response.content_type = "text/plain"
  context.response.print "Hello world!"
end

address = server.bind_tcp 80
LibC.setuid(NEW_UID) 
server.listen
puts "Listening on http://#{address}"

puts "=== Processing requests as: #{`whoami`.strip}"
```

Kemal (v1.0.0) users:

```
PORT = 80
NEW_UID = System::User.find_by(name: "my-sys-usr").id.to_i
Kemal.run do |config|
  config.server.not_nil!.bind_tcp PORT
  LibC.setuid(NEW_UID)
  STDERR.puts "Running as: #{`whoami`.strip}"
end
```

If you're using a shard that does not grant you direct access to it's `HTTP::Server` instance, you should find an alternative shard. It's also possible to monkey-patch the `HTTP::Server#listen` method, but it's not recommended.

Comment: I don't think you need to monkey patch. You can call `server.bind` and `server.listen` separately and put `LibC setuid` in between.

Comment: @JohannesMüller Thanks. I updated the answer with your answer. Feel free to edit if you have time to review. It's set as a community wiki.